# Handling AWS request and sending status code (200 OK) using AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have worked on SpringBoot rest api,

I have to convert below endpoints into AWS lambda function.

1) **/service/promotion/ping/{pignId}**.    get single object of ping

2) **/service/promotion/ping**.     get complete ping details

I have visited on AWS offical website for reference, 
I had successfully converted first endpoint

**/service/promotion/ping/{pignId}.**

into AWS lambda function.

In first endpoint I was knew that **{pignId}** was coming in request param with type Integer so i have simply used AWS's RequestHandler interface to handler request like

```
public class CustomRequest implements RequestHandler<Integer, MyResponse> {
```

In second endpoint there is no request param means (Integer) coming in request, So

**1) Which Handler should I used?**

**2)I want to send response code 200(OK) if endpoint works properly?**

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK there is no separate handler for that use-case. Can you try the same `RequestHandler<Integer, MyResponse>` without passing anything or doing anything with the input in the overridden method? Also note that in the latest version, `RequestHandler` is deprecated by `RequestHandler2`. For reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/handlers/RequestHandler.html

Comment: @MadhuBhat Thank you for your response, I did same as you mentioned above, Have you any idea how to send HTTP status code 200 if success?

Comment: Have you used API gateway along with the lambda code?

Comment: @MadhuBhat I have worked on SpringBoot rest api, Amazon is new for me.

Comment: Using lambda with RequestHandler would only return the response that you specify. But in case you want it to be an HTTP response with the status code, you would need to use AWS's API Gateway too. Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/aws-lambda-api-gateway

Comment: You may try using RequestHandler2, as it looks like it might send the http response https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/handlers/RequestHandler2.html